# Failed to resolve AndroidX.AppCompat.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableWrapper in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a build error after updating the Firebase.Messaging.Service nuget in my Xamarin android project.
I have the latest VS 2022 Version 17.5.4. and Android project is targeting Android 13.

the logs:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellSearchView/ClipDrawableWrapper::.ctor(Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve AndroidX.AppCompat.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableWrapper
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(649,5): error XALNK7000:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I am getting exact same error, Downgrading Androidx.AppCompact, doesn't help, it only works if we do "None" for Linker setting, but then APK size is double for us. All nuget package are updated, obj/bin are deleted .vs file is deleted nothing helps.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem...
Through trial and error, I downgraded the package version
**Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources** downgrade to version **1.5.1.1**....
After that my project came together....

Comment: This seems to have fixed it for me. Thank you Team Xamarin. I look forward to running into more arcane cr*p when we are forced to move our codebase to MAUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, then restart your Visual studio  and try again.

If the problem persist, try to update all the nugets in your app to the latest ones.

Comment: those suggest doesn't work, I even try to download Androidx.appComact nuget doesn't help. I even add fake Using for Drawables to make sure it get included for linker. Doesn't work. app work with "linker" as none .. so it is linker that is remove this function now. Anyways we can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DrawableWrapperCompat` (`androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperCompat`) was added in appcompat [version 1.6.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#version_160_3)